# Why do I get a Reference Error in EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I add a title to a header of my sidenav and my code runs fine in the EJS template. But when I add a second output in a list I get a reference error.

```
<div class="col-3 flex-nowrap">
<nav id="sidebar">
    <!-- Sidebar Header -->
    <div class="sidebar-header text-center">
        <h1 id="notification"><%= title %></h1>
    </div>
    <!-- Sidebar Links -->
    <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><%= list %></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Privacy & Security</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Payment Setting</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Transaction History</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Trust & Verfication</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">My Education Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Promotions</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="cancel"><a><strong>Cancel Account</strong></a></ul>
</nav>
```

This is how I am including the partial above in my code

```
<%-include("./partials/sidebar.ejs",
        {title: "Notification"}, 
        {list: "Edit Profile"})
        %>
```

Is this not the proper format? I can't seem to figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: I am not too familiar with ejs but it makes sense to me that title and list should be in the same object

Answer (score 0):

refer : http://ejs.co/

You need second param as

```
{title: "Notification",
 list: "Edit Profile"}
```